# Looking for online abstract algebra courses making use of computer algebra systems

Tags: abstract-algebra, online-instruction, computer-programs

- preferably areas of algebra of value and interest to computing practitioners.
- any level from introductory to (say) Grobner bases.
- preferably using open source computer algebra software.
- no preference as to Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.
- in English or French.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications](http://abstract.ups.edu/aata/) by Judson and Beezer.  It doesn't get to Grobner bases but does cover the standard material (and some non-standard stuff, too).  It has Sage code and exercises throughout.  I will also add that it includes chapters on coding theory, cryptography and lattices and boolean algebras, all of interest to people in computer science.